# Connecting to remote MySQL host resolves to my IP address?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server that allows for remote connections (I know it works because there are other people that connect to it remotely), but when I connect from my computer, the host address is resolving to my home IP address?

When I do a ping on the MySQL host address, it gives me the correct IP address it should resolve to, but when I put the MySQL host address in a a MySQL connect command, it says `Access denied for user@{MY_HOME_IP_HERE}`

Here is a screenshot[image]

I am connecting from a Windows 7 machine. I have tried connecting using the command prompt and also HeidiSQL with same result.

Ideas?

Comment: In the error message there is the IP of the computer you connect from. You should grant access to user `david@173.10.93.222`.

Comment: this works only if that is a static ip. If it is dynamic this will fail as soon as the IP change and then he needs to use a wildcard (that is not recommended)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I run into the same problem yesterday, and it took me the full day to figure it out so find here my 5 cents.

You mentioned other people can access to it, so if you already have access to the mysql db from another location (or others), you can ask them to run this:

```
select user, host from mysql.user;
```

This will basically show the users that can access the database, and where they can access from (a % symbol means from everywhere).

When you are running

```
mysql -h hostname -u david -p
```

the hostname is indeed the host where mysql is, that is why dns lookups utilities (like dig, in this case you used ping) will resolve to the host ip.
The reason why you are getting

> access denied for david@yourIP

is because in the mysql.user table, your user is not allowed to log in from there.
Basically you need to check in the mysql.user table where your user can access from. An admin could run something like:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host = '%' WHERE user = 'david';
```

Note that this is not recommended without proper firewall rules, as it will allow to connect from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that your user is not authorized to access to the mysql server from that IP. In mysql server alter your user to add your IP (if public) or use a wildcard if your IP is dynamic (less safe solution). 
If you use phpMyAdmin it is easy to get

Comment: Asterisk (*) is not allowed as a wildcard in host name part. You should use percent sign instead (%). For more secure solution, in case of dynamic address, it may be possible to use a wildcard for a subnet: `david@173.10.%`